# How to convert list of SBOMs to one CSV file?

Tags: csv

I have the ability to create multiple SBOMs for many projects in Synopsys Black Duck Hub.  They can be in the SPDX or CycloneDX SBOM standards in a JSON, YAML, RDF, or tag:value formats.

Is there a way to combine all of the SBOMs into one CSV file which lists all of the dependencies?

Comment: This isn't a security question. This is a file combining question.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? Do you just want a list of files and dependencies? Is there a reason you don't want to do this manually?

Comment: I asked it here since Black Duck is a security SCA tool and SBOMs are used in security risk assessments.  I have tried the sbom-combiner and sbom-composer but had issues with installation.

I am not doing this manually because there are too many SBOMs to combine into one to be done manually.